# Display information about objects in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

So, I successfully created a blank JFrame, my purpose for this was so that I could clearly display information about some objects to the user of the program. However, almost everything I read online was concerning buttons and things like that. All I want is an area divided up into 10 parts that can display whatever `toString()` of my object returned.

Any ideas on how to start this, or where to look (tutorials/the documentation had a lot of information, I had no idea where to look exactly).

Comment: I'd start with [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html).

Comment: A JTextArea can display plain text just fine. Read the swing tutorial. You'll also need a layout manager to lay out those areas in your frame. Learning Swing takes some time. You can't expect to just have a look at the doc and come up with a working application.

Comment: Thank you. I realize that this will take some time, but I wanted to at least start learning it with the purpose of achieving my goal, so I wanted to narrow my focus down a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me you are just trying to run a console program. Trying to create an entire Swing program without any knowledge may be difficult. I'd suggest just using a [`JOptionPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) <-- click me to see my tutorial

```
String name = "Me";
String age = 30;
String gender = "male";
String location = "earth";

String message = "Name:" + name +
                 "\nAge: " + age +
                 "\Gender: " + gender +
                 "\Location: " + location;

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
```

Or if you have an object or multiple objects that you want printed to the dialog

```
Object[] objects = new Object[10];
for (int i = 0; i < objects.lengthl i++){
    objects[i] = new Object();
}  

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (Object o : objects){
    sb.append(o + "\n");
} 

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sb.toString());
```

The code prints 10 objects, one on each line in the message dialog

Comment: This method seems pretty useful, but I also plan on learning Swing. I'll try this first since it seems quicker and hopefully I'll eventually learn enough Swing to do this.

Comment: Here's the [official Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)